# Can't hear people on skype

Tags: skype

Since I installed Ubuntu it has been wonderful and im a noob with it but there is just one issue. I Can't hear over Skype im wondering if there’s a fix 
Thanks in advance

Skype Sound Panel - https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ51T.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug inside of skype, which affected Windows too !

After update of skype (under Windows) this bug was fixed.

Look for update-feature inside of skype program.